# Need help to install Gnome

Tags: gnome, 22.04, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

Recently I managed to install **ubuntu(22.04)**, but when updating the applications in the Ubuntu software I had several connection problems and while clicking on update, several messages appeared (like black dialog boxes [like this ,but I have solved this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJCiR.png)) making it difficult to update.

Somehow the apps I had to update disappeared without completing 100% .

1. I have already reached my version of **Gnome (42.5)**, but there are **characteristics of the version (42)** for example **that are not in mine**, for example the text editor name menu preferences in the images that I have placed.
   [My text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mJFx.png) ,( 42 version img: https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:720/format:webp/1*4t7Ewz71bb4FhtXfe8pdyA.png)
2. **I already logged out and clicked on the gear button** and the Gnome option **did not appear**.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @user535733 has already noted, it's unclear what your question is, as there appear to be many unrelated issues mentioned. Since this is a brand new install, I'd recommend that you just reinstall the OS, but this time, observe where/when you start running into problems, and document them (note any errors captured in the OS logs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing two *different* text editing applications: "Text Editor" (`gnome-text-editor`) and "Gedit" (`gedit`). They are separate applications.

Gedit is the default text editor in Ubuntu 22.04.
It was replaced by Text Editor in Ubuntu 22.10.
Both are available in the Ubuntu repositories for all supported releases, and you can install either (or both) and use whichever you like.

Comment: Thank you . I was using as reference , if I manage to install.